# Javascript Datatable limit amount of characters shown in a cell

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I am creating a DataTable in Javascript, which has the following properties:

```
var dtable = $('.ssdatatable').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500], [10, 25, 50, 100, 500]],
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sDom": "TBflrtip",
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": ajSource,
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "bJqueryUI": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    //"bAutoLength": false,
    //"bLengthChange": false,
    "recordsFiltered": 0,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sServerMethod": "POST",
    "responsive": true,
    "fixedHeader": true,
    "buttons": [
            'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ],
    "aoColumns": [
        //columns
    ]
});
```

One of the particular columns is a Description, which has a LOT of text in it. The width of columns is fixed, however because of that, the height of my rows are blowing out of proportions, making page x10 of its intended size.

My question is: **is there anything I can add inside the properties to make it show only N characters, and by hitting limit it would be something like:**

```
|text textte...|
|     Show More|
```

(I tried commented out options, did do me any good)

Or would I need to use some method or modify css?

Comment: What I did is took the first x characters and put it in the cell, Then put the whole thing in a tool tip.  I used a tool tip plugin to make sure it was easy to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given data:

```
var mydt = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, { a: 5, b: 6, c: 7, d: 8 }, { a: 10, b: 12, c: 13, d: 14 }];


                    $("#tbl2").DataTable({
                        columnDefs: [{ targets:[0] }],
                        data: mydt, columns: [{ data: "a" }, { data: "b" }, { data: "c" }, { data: "d" }],
                        createdRow: function (row, data, c, d) {

                         // so for each row, I am pulling out the 2nd td
                         // and adding a title attribute from the 
                        // data object associated with the row.


                            $(row).children(":nth-child(2)").attr("title", data.b)


                        },



                  and the rest
```

here is a working one in jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/wbpn7z57/7/ note that this one has data in a different format but it works (on the first name column)

Comment: That's a good start, thank you. But is there a way to expand the rest of the text, should the user desire to do so?

Comment: Pity there is no easy way to include link to expand row height and show the rest of the text, but your suggestion is a good direction.

Comment: actually there is.  https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/wbpn7z57/26/  uses qtip to display the name.  You can change the style from the default and make it more pronounced.  Or, you can use jquery mouse enter and mouse leave to display a dialog showing all the info

Comment: I use http://qtip2.com/ just this way at work.  I make it show up much bigger than the default size and match my sites coloring

Comment: in another case, we tied it to ajax and it goes back and gets the users complete accouant information

Comment: And here is even a more robust version: https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/wbpn7z57/31/

Comment: Awesome! I'll definitely try all these options on Tuesday once I get back to work!

Comment: Didn't have time to play around with the code in question, however, I am also intrigued by the design of the table header. Upon elimination, I found that dataTables.jqueryui.js is responsible for it. I added appropriate js and css to the bundle. I only managed to make the header grey, but cannot make those arrows to appear. How do I make those sorting arrows to appear?

Comment: Do the columns sort change when you click on them? If the answer is yes, my guess is that the relationship between the jquery.ui css and the jquery ui css icon was changed.  (that happened to me because I was combining all my css into a single minimized file and changed its location.

Comment: The answer to your last question is yes. As for the topic in hand, I managed to replace text excess with ... However, the floating text does not appear. Did I miss something? I used your snippet from first fiddle.

Comment: You mean, qtip is necessary either way? I haven't found qtip added at your first fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/wbpn7z57/7/

Comment: My very first one just uses the standard "title" attribute on the cell.  Did you verify the attribute was added to the table cell?

Comment: What does this line do exactly? `$(row).children(":nth-child(10)").attr("title", data[1]);`

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem - only I wanted to show all the text when the table is exported and thus only limit the text, when displayed. So based on this blog https://datatables.net/blog/2016-02-26, I further developed the code in order to allow the whole text to be shown when the table is exported.

In order to do so, I altered the code so text > 50 char is not removed, but instead wrapped in a span which is then hidden from CSS.

The function code looks like this:

```
function(data, type, row) {
        if (type === 'display' && data != null) {
          data = data.replace(/<(?:.|\\n)*?>/gm, '');


  if(data.length > 50) {
        return '<span class=\"show-ellipsis\">' + data.substr(0, 50) + '</span><span class=\"no-show\">' + data.substr(50) + '</span>';
      } else {
        return data;
      }
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }
```

Then from the CSS file you can add:

```
span.no-show{
    display: none;
}
span.show-ellipsis:after{
    content: "...";
}
```

Comment: just the perfect answer! Works like a charm:)

Answer (score 0):

// DataTable created the createRow hook to allow the row html to be updated after it was created.

-- row is the current row being created
-- data is the data object associated with the row.

```
createdRow: function (row, data, c, d) {


  $(row) gets the tr in a jQuery object
  $(row).children() gets all of the td's in the row
 (":nth-child(2)") gets the 2nd td in the row. Note, this is 1 based value,not 0 based.

  .attr is the jquery command that adds the "title" attribute to the td.
  the "title" is missed name but too late now.

   data.b matches the data structured used to populate the table.
   The actual structure of this data structure is dependent on your data source   so you would actually have to check it.
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, I will include this info while working on my piece.

Answer (score 0):

In the below example code block:

Whereas **"Targets": 2** indicates column index, **"data":"description"** points out column name that wanted to be manipulated. When we look at the render function, **description** column is limited to 100 characters length.

```
var dtable = $('.ssdatatable').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500], [10, 25, 50, 100, 500]],
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sDom": "TBflrtip",
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": ajSource,
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "bJqueryUI": false,
    .....
    {
        "targets": 2,
        "data":"description",
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
           if (type === 'display') {
             data = typeof data === 'string' && data.length > 100 ? data.substring(0, 100) + '...' : data;
           }
            return data;
        }
    },
});
```