# Jquery / Datatable - How to shorten and show a tooltip when hovering a column value?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have the following jquery datatable. How to shorten and show a tooltip when hovering the value of the "Description" column?

```
var tableRequest = $('#tableRequest').DataTable({
    data: this.Request,
    columns: [
        { title: "ID", data: "ID" },
        { title: "Description", data: "Description" },
        { title: "Request", data: "Request" },
        { title: "Status", data: "Status" },
        { title: "Date", data: "Date" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: making shorten column header text "Description" or column value?

Comment: @rohit-mittal The column value

Comment: Check if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644720/javascript-datatable-limit-amount-of-characters-shown-in-a-cell

Comment: @rohit-mittal I don't think so. I'm not understanding the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to integrate Datatable eclipse plugin. Check a working example on below link:

https://datatables.net/blog/2016-02-26

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thank you, but how can I show a tooltip when hovering it?

Comment: @Talan there is a working example shown where cell complete text showing in tooltip. Have a look of linked datatable and hover your over cell. You will get that.